# Ajust div width to fit text after line-break

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to resize a div width to make it always fit the text inside even when there is a line-break.

Is there a way to modify the width to make it fit the text after a line break using javascript?

```css
    body{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #container {
        border: 15px solid orange;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #firstDiv{
        border: 10px solid brown;     
        width: 130px;
        margin: auto 20px;
    }
    #secondDiv{
        border: 10px solid skyblue;         
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto 20px;
    }
    #icon{
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    #thirdDiv{
        border: 5px solid yellowgreen;
        width: 200px;    
        margin: auto 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="firstDiv">FIRST</div>
      <div id="secondDiv">
        <span id="icon"></span>
        <span id="legend">I want the #secondDiv width to fit this text</span>
      </div>
      <div id="thirdDiv">THIRD</div>
    </div>
```

**Edits:**

The problem is because there is some blank space at the end of the `#secondDiv` the space between `#firstDiv` and `#secondDiv` appears not the same than between `#secondDiv` and `#thirDiv` when there is no borders.

Comment: Do you mean the flexbox in the #container or in #secondDiv?

Comment: you accepted an answer but you seems to still have an issue. So it's solved or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instruct that element to use all of the remaining space (`width:100%`) the text will fill whatever space it can.

```css
body{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #container {
        border: 15px solid orange;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #firstDiv{
        border: 10px solid brown;     
        width: 130px;
        margin: auto 20px;
    }
    #secondDiv{
        border: 10px solid skyblue;         
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto 20px;
        width:100%; /* Instruct element to take 100% of the remaining space  */
    }
    #icon{
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    #thirdDiv{
        border: 5px solid yellowgreen;
        width: 200px;    
        margin: auto 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div id="firstDiv">FIRST</div>
      <div id="secondDiv">
        <span id="icon"></span>
        <span id="legend">I want the #secondDiv width to fit this text</span>
      </div>
      <div id="thirdDiv">THIRD</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the text to break to keep it responsive

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Then please clarify your question. What exactly do you want here?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed some css code to make this three div be `inline` and deleted `display:flex`

```css
    body{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #container {
        border: 15px solid orange;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #firstDiv{
        border: 10px solid brown;     
        width: 130px;
        margin: auto 5px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #secondDiv{
        border: 10px solid skyblue;         
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto 5px;
        width:auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #icon{
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    #thirdDiv{
        border: 5px solid yellowgreen;
        margin: auto 5px;
        display:inline-block;
        width:auto;
       text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="firstDiv">FIRST</div>
      <div id="secondDiv">
        <span id="icon"></span>
        <span id="legend">I want the #secondDiv width to fit this text</span>
      </div>
      <div id="thirdDiv">THIRD</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But, by getting rid of Flexbox, you've lost all the alignment and centering.

Comment: No, it odes not. Your result is not what the OP is looking for. Your result has the the middle box no longer centered. See my answer.

Comment: you asked about fitting div

Comment: No. I commented that by getting rid of Flexbox, the alignment and centering is off now, which it is.

Comment: not matter anymore i just wanted to help. i can easily change my code for centering without flex but it seems you got your answer.

Comment: i didnlt see any comment actually i answered befor comment

Comment: My comment was right here. It was a comment to your answer. I think you may be confused as to who and what you are responding to.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Then please clarify your question. What exactly do you want here?

Comment: I'm not mad. I'm pointing out that I believe you think you are responding to the OP and you're not. I didn't post the question and you didn't change my code at all.

Comment: when you got your answer what this matter?? you want me to delete my try?

Comment: To both of you, thank you for your help. It's my mistake. My question was not clear enough at start.

Comment: i did what i tought is correct im not here to spam. so why you are trying to say i am doing wrong